# Xcode iPhone - How does one change image into text to manipulate?

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, text, uiimage

Basically this is what I want to be able to do: I have a picture on my computer which is called image.png. If I change the file name by pushing F2 and change the name of it to image.txt, it changes the file extension and the image becomes a text document. When you open it you see all the image data which you can change (if you change it the picture doesn't come back however). You could edit, such as add a line after the image code that won't affect the image. After doing this, you can rename image.txt back to image.png and the picture will come back.

How do I get this to work coding wise? What I'm doing so far is saving my image using UIImagePNGRepresentation with the path being the documents directory with a .txt at the end of it. I then do NSString withcontentsoffile which is depreceated and it shows some code but it isn't the same as when I do it on my PC changing the extensions. If I do NSString with conentsoffile withencoding, the encoding makes nothing appear. I tried NSUTF8String....I'm not near the mac so I'm now exactly sure.

Basically I want to add text to an image (which if added at the bottom of the .txt will not mess up the image) and then change it back to an image and I can't seem to get this to work.

Need anymore info ask. I'll be checking back very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSMutableData * newData = [imageData mutableCopy];

NSString * string = @"Data to be appended";

[newData appendData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

UIImage * newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:newData];
[newData release];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works wonders. It places the string at the end and allows the image to still be viewed. I marked your answer as the best one but I have one more question if you don't mind answering...

For reading the file into a string so that I can read back the message I use NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pngPath]; which works but it says it is deprecated which is not good. It wants it like: NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pngPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; but the encoding doesn't display anything. What encoding should I use?

Comment: Why don't you read it as an `NSData` object? You will get it in the raw form just as above. You can access the c style content via `bytes`  method.

Comment: Sorry as I'm kinda new but how would I go about reading it as an NSData?

Comment: `NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pngPath];`

Comment: How would I be able to read the data instead of the NSData? I have the data I need separated by **com.myapp** and was using  myText = [[myText componentsSeparatedByString:stringSeperator] objectAtIndex:1];

Once I figure that out I should be set. Thank you so much for all the help so far.

Comment: I managed to figure it out but later realized that this whole idea would not work for what I'm trying to do because once the image leaves the phone the data appended is lost.